# i have a staticmethod that is returning socket.socket and socket._RetAddress

Tags: python, class, sockets, oop, static

I have a method that is returning socket.socket and socket._RetAddress :

```py
@staticmethod
def init_socket(_addr:str,_port:int):
        s=socket.socket()
        s.bind((_addr,_port))
        s.listen()
        print(chalk.red("WAITING FOR CONNECTIONS..."))
        c,addr=s.accept()
        os.system("cls")
        return (c,addr)
```

i want to indicate user that this method is returning socket.socket and socket._RetAddress. for eg :

```
def foo() -> str:
    return "bar"
```

here, intellisense will show that this method returns string object

how to do this in my case?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: `-> Tuple[socket.socket, socket._RetAddress]`…?

Comment: What is `socket._RetAddress`?  That's not defined in `socket`.  for `AF_INET` (the default socket address family), it would be `Tuple[socket.socket, Tuple[str, int]]` since `addr` is a tuple of `(host, port)`